# Rails 6 & deliver_later doesn't affect ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

Tags: delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-6

After upgrading to Rails 6 I am noticing that default mailer's `.deliver_later` is not working the same as in Rails 5.

Configuration:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
```

When running `Mailer.register_email(...).deliver_later` - nothing is stored in `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`. This array gets filled if I run `perform_enqueued_jobs` - it seams like `queue_adapter = :inline` doesn't work the way I expect it to work.

If I run `Mailer.send(...).deliver_now` then `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` has proper value in it.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this?

Comment: This behavior changed somewhere between Rails 5 and Rails 6. I couldn't find where, but I did see that Rails is now calling `perform_enqueued_jobs` in their Minitest email helpers. They add a filter to ensure only email jobs are performed this way.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/test_helper.rb#L37

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem in my tests. A search on the Internet yielded nothing, so I started experimenting.

I tried wrapping the call method of sending mail in

```
assert_emails 1 do
  Mailer.register_email(...).deliver_later
end
```

After that, `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` populated correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**The issue**

The issue lies in two new lines of code added to Rails 6 ([line 1](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v5.2.8.1...v6.0.6#diff-e3e4ac1142b6f7a74a4472f2c5716679b7fc988d4e4fe3b6cc255dfeddf789b4R35) & [line 2](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v5.2.8.1...v6.0.6#diff-b2555388d34f4657f98f10cd106ccac94433e322044fb9455724b09247984850R57)),
where basically, the callback `before_setup` defined [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v4.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb#L80) (in RSpec) and [here](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/blob/dcdd882fbe01ad9c230f434d8def19f5cbb26b53/lib/minitest/test.rb#L156) (in Minitest) gets overridden ([by this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.6/activejob/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb#L36-L46)), thus forcing the   [queue_adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.6/activejob/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb#L20) to be the [test adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.6/activejob/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb#L64) instead of the one defined by `config.active_job.queue_adapter`.

**Workaround**

So in order to use the `queue_adapter` defined by `config.active_job.queue_adapter` and therefore restore the Rails 5 behaviour we can do something like the below.

```
# spec/support/active_job/test_helper.rb
module ActiveJob
  module TestHelper
    def before_setup
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, @andres-leon! You saved me quite some time to debug this issue for me! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the exact number of emails could easily change, this is another option:

```
assert_changes 'enqueued_jobs.size' do
  # Some code that sends email with deliver_later
end
```

This allows you to test that emails were sent but it disregards the exact number (which is a limitation of the `asserts_emails` method - other than this, the `asserts_emails` method is great).
I found that the `enqueued_jobs` method is very helpful in testing anything background jobs, including `deliver_later`

NOTE: the above example only checks that the enqueued jobs list was changed. If you want to be more specific and check that the queue was changed with emails, you should do this:

```
assert_changes 'enqueued_jobs.select {|job| job["job_class"] == "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"}.size' do
  # Some code that sends email with deliver_later
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`assert_enqueued_emails` might also help in this situation